# Youtube Chrome extension with OAuth2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I am trying to make a Chrome extension which will allow me to view the playlist info of a Youtube page  provided it points to a playlist. I want it to show the info whether it is a public list OR one of my private lists (so I have to use both the YouTube Data API and **OAuth2**). Here is my code:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "YT Web Extension",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Tests CP's first YT web extension with OAuth2",
    "key": YYYYY,
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": XXXXX,
        "scopes": [
            "profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "youtube.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "identity"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    if (message.request === "get_access") {
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(auth_token) {
            console.log(auth_token);
        });
    } else if (message.request === "get_list") {
        // pulls playlistId from url:
        const pageURL = message.pageURL;
        const pattern = /list=[^&]+/g;
        if (pageURL.match(pattern)) {
            chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
                console.log(token);
                const playlistId = pageURL.match(pattern).join("").slice(5);
                const key = "AIzaSyBWFCRNEx-EkP0L2E_tn-R6o74hwSY6sOM";
                // Retreives data with the following parameters:
                let fetch_url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=' + playlistId + '&key=' + key;
                let fetch_options = {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                };
                fetch(fetch_url, fetch_options)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => console.log(res))
            });
        } else {
            console.log(pageURL); // print just the URL if no playlistId is found
        }
    }
});
```

**youtube.js**

```
const pageURL = window.location.href;

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({request: "get_list", pageURL: pageURL})
```

I know my OAuth key is good, because it works fine when I plug in the id of one of my private lists on the "Try This API" on the Google Developer Tools.

When I run the extension the login page gives me 2 choices: my email or my YouTube account. When I choose my YouTube account, the background page shows an error saying "User is not signed in", but when I choose my email and go to a private playlist, it does not show me the info (public playlists work fine here). So now I am backed into a corner. How do I get out?